# Hot swapping bindings per request

Tags: asp.net-web-api, ninject

We have an ASP.NET Web API app which uses Ninject for DI. This works perfect for use. One of the improvements we were considering is the ability to swap out parts of functionality per request based on some sort of unique identifier.

Example. Two customers use our restful api. Both get the same functionality. A third customer has paid for the super version of our api. He makes the request, we load the super dll and bind the super implementations to the standard interfaces.

Essentially what I am looking to see is can we load a DLL and swap out bindings per request using Web API and Ninject.

EDIT:

So both answers are correct for the original question but my intention is different and it is my fault for not explaining it correctly. What we have is a base layer of functionality that everyone gets. On top of this we also have the ability to implement custom logic on a per customer basis that overrides this functionality. This logic is stored as a DLL in Azure Blob Storage.

What we would like to do is when a customer makes a request is go get the DLL, bind all the custom services and then service the request using these new bindings.

Is hot swapping not the best way to do this? We are new enough to ninject so this may be a common thing that is implemented in a different way to what we are considering.

To some up, we would like to be able to service custom bindings on a per customer basis.

EDIT 2:

We use conditional bindings for items were we know that we have alternate implementations but in the scenario above until we get the customer info and scan the dll we do not know if we have alternate bindings. We don't even know if there is a dll.

We would like to do it this way so we can drop the file in rather than referencing it in the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't mind that you can swap out bindings per request. But what you can do is to use conditional binding.

**Example - default bindings:**

```
protected override Ninject.IKernel CreateKernel()
{
    var kernel = new StandardKernel();

    kernel.Bind<IAuthorizationService>()
        .To<AuthorizationService>()
        .InRequestScope();

    kernel.Bind<IService>()
        .To<BasicService>();

    return kernel;
}
```

It will inject (on place where `IService` is needed) a `BasicService` for some basic user and `ExtraService` for VIP user.

For more information about various ways of conditional binding see [Ninject - Contextual binding](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding).

**EDIT**

I think you can still use conditional binding. You will only need to propagate the `IKernel` to place where you want to register components from new dll. For example I have this in my `global.asax` for dynamically loading dll modules - it runs on app startup.

**Loading modules:**

```
private void LoadAssemblies(IKernel kernel) {
    foreach (var fileName in Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"), "*.dll")) {
        Assembly loadedAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile(fileName);
        try {
            var moduleRegistrations = loadedAssembly.GetTypes()
                .Where(t => t.IsClass && t.IsAbstract == false && typeof (IMyModuleRegistration).IsAssignableFrom(t));

            foreach (var moduleRegType in moduleRegistrations ) {
                IMyModuleRegistration moduleReg = (IMyModuleRegistration) Activator.CreateInstance(moduleRegType);
                moduleReg.RegisterComponents(kernel);
            }
        }
        catch (ReflectionTypeLoadException exception) {
            ....
        }
    }
}
```

**Module definition:**

```
public class MyExtraModule : IMyModuleRegistration
{
     public void RegisterComponents(IKernel kernel)
     {
         kernel.Bind<IService>()
               .To<ExtraService>()
               .When(x => x.ParentContext
                           .Kernel.Get<IAuthorizationService>()
                           .IsVIPUser());
     }
}
```

`ExtraService` will be used only when dll with `MyExtraModule` is loaded.

**EDIT 2**

You can download that dll from somewhere. Load it and then test it if it implements your registration interface. Then call that registration and you are done. The only problem I see is: where to store the reference to `IKernel` - probably some static property in `HttpApplication` will be enough. You should also track already loaded dlls.

Or in later versions of `Ninject` I can suggest extending the `NinjectModule` and then load it into kernel with `kernel.Load(..)` method. Look at this [Modules and kernel](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Modules-and-the-Kernel) - specially in part **Dynamic Module Loading** - maybe it is what you are looking for.

Comment: I have modified the question to better explain myself. Could you perhaps take another look?

Comment: Updated my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: I have given you an upvote there as it is closer to what I need. The only issue I see is I do not know anything about the dll until I get the url in the request to find and load it so I cannot do it at startup. I need to be able to essentially lazyload in the dll at the first request of the specific user and mind the services for just that user to use. I am thinking the conventions method can help with this.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not aware of any conventional methods for this. But I have updated my answer with some additional suggestions ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Use conditional bindings:

```
Bind<IMyService>().To<MyService>();
Bind<IMyService>().To<MyServiceForVIPs>().When(ctx => CurrentPrincipalIsVIP());
```

Comment: I have modified the question to better explain myself. Could you perhaps take another look?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you know the core ninject modules. You can load all core ninject modules into the kernel. When the special user arrives you could unload the core module und load the user specific module into the kernel.

A better approach would be to have a special kernel in the plugin area. So actually a kernel per plugin approach wich loads the required core modules and adds the user specific ones if any. But that might have performance impacts!

Comment: Yes, all the core modules are loaded regardless at the start. The sub kernels idea is interesting, I notice there is a child kernel set of extensions too.